# PHP: Class 'PragmaRX\Google2FA\Google2FA' not found

Tags: linux, php

I'm trying to use  Class 'PragmaRX\Google2FA\Google2FA' with the "use" command in PHP, but I keep getting not found, even though the file is in /usr/share/php.

CentOS 7. I've yum uninstalled and re-installed, tried changing the include path in php.ini, tried explicitly setting it with set_include_path. No luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install it using composer [as suggested in their readme on github](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/google2fa-php#installing)? Also not sure if this is on-topic for serverfault, maybe better ask this question on stackoverflow.com

Comment: No, I installed it via yum. I don't konw how composer works. I'll post on StackOverflow.